# How to add csv MimeType to spring content-negotiation?

Tags: spring, csv, spring-mvc

I'm creating a webservice method that can serve xml, json and csv output:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "text/csv"})
public Rsp get() {
}
```

Problem: I somehow need to add the `text/csv` content type to my `configureContentNegotiation()`. But how? Because a String is not accepted, and a `MediaType.TEXT_CSV` does not exist (even though [RFC7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111) defines it as a valid mimetype.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .favorParameter(true)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .mediaType("csv", "text/csv"); //this is invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: In a Spring Boot application you can put `spring.mvc.media-types.csv = text/csv` in your application.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv"));
```

or even configure as follows in `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.media-types.json=application/json
spring.mvc.media-types.xml=application/xml
spring.mvc.media-types.csv=text/csv
```

Comment: Great example! It helped for me