# How to accept text/csv as content-type in spring-web servlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest, spring-web

I want to create a simple webservice that produces `text/csv` content. But I cannot request it:

```
@RestController
public class MyServlet {
    @PostMapping(produces = {"text/csv", "application/json"})
    public Object post() {
        //...
    }
}

spring.mvc.contentnegotiation.media-types.csv=text/csv
```

When I send a post request with `Content-Type: text/csv` as http header, I'm getting the following error:

415: `Content type 'text/csv' not supported`

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ContentNegotiationConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .favorParameter(true) //favor &format=csv
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .parameterName(format);
                //.mediaType("csv", new MediaType("text", "csv")) //also tried without success
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to generate a csv file for your user?

Comment: have you tried adding `consumes="text/csv"`??

Comment: Is it consumer instead of producer

Comment: No, `consumes` is for what data is received from the user. But my user is not sending anything, so consumes is ignored here. I want to generate a csv file.

Comment: @mohammedkhan it's not a duplicate. Especially I want the content negotiation to already select the correct response content type, as configured above. The query parameter `&format=csv` should be favored, and as a result a `text/csv` should be generated, as configured in the `application.properties`.

Comment: @membersound how come [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778791/how-to-add-csv-mimetype-to-spring-content-negotiation) and answer worked and how it not working in the same configuration(both from you). So are you missing any configuration?

Comment: do you have `@EnableWebMvc` on `ContentNegotiationConfiguration` class? What version of Spring are you targeting?

Comment: `spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE`, which automatically adds `@EnableWebMvc`. I can also see during debug, that my `ContentNegotiationConfiguration` is loaded and the configurer actually contains `text/csv` as media type. The question is why it is not matched...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you (client) expect csv content, client should pass `text/csv` as `Accept` header not `Content-Type`.