# ResponseEntity doesnot accept text/csv: SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Iam trying to create an API that accept both files like CSV and json body request. I tried using `ResponseEntity` object in spring boot.

The endpoint looks as below.

```
    @PostMapping(value="/csv",consumes=MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public void createConsumer(RequestEntity<?> data){



    }
```

The content headers is set via postman.

The `Content-Type` is `text/csv` and `Accept` is `*/*`.

The error thrown is

```
2021-03-12 19:28:10.344  WARN 5780 --- [nio-8089-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/csv' not supported]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to accept text/csv as content-type in spring-web servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839422/how-to-accept-text-csv-as-content-type-in-spring-web-servlet)

Comment: @deadshot Its not working for me. I have already set `Content-Type` is `text/csv` and `Accept` is `*/*`.

Comment: Are you uploading files or are you posting CSV and/or JSON data as the request body. Your question suggest the first, your code the second (and obviously it won't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 2 methods. If you use file as request body, use MulpartFile and corresponding 'consumes=..', and for json use @RequestBody:

```
  @PostMapping(value="/csv", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
        public void createConsumer(@RequestParam MultipartFile file){
          
        }

@PostMapping(value="/csv", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public void createConsumerFromJson(@RequestBody SomeObject json){
          
        }
```

Set content type as form-data in body in Postman for MultipartFile, like

[image]

Comment: But the problem is that I want to accept data such as json in body as well as file type data